# Newline character is getting inserted in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python programming and need some help here. My code is as below :

```
reg_file = "list.txt"
my_file = open(reg_file, "r")
for i in my_file.readlines():
    print "score for {}:".format(i)
my_file.close()
```

file "list.txt" contains:

```
1
2
3
.
.
200
```

I need the o/p in the below format :

```
score for 1:
score for 2:
score for 3:
.
.
score for 200:
```

But instead I'm getting something like this :

```
score for 1
:
score for 2
:
score for 3
:
.
.
score for 200
:
```

Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: You don’t need the `readlines`, note; just do `for i in my_file:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to strip the line:

Change

```
print "score for {}:".format(i)
```

to

```
print "score for {}:".format(i.strip())
```

Comment: thanks. that worked.